# EasyMock failing test case with "Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded" error

Tags: unit-testing, powermock, easymock, matcher

Let's name our test file as ExecutorTest.java. In this file we have a unit test case which mocks a static method using EasyMock like this -

```
Executor exectorInstance;
PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(SomeClass.class, "someStaticMethod", Map.class, SomeOtherClass.class);
EasyMock.expect(SomeClass.someStaticMethod(Mockito.any(Map.class), SomeOtherClassObject)).andReturn(false);
PowerMock.replayAll();
exectorInstance.execute();
```

Executor.java -

```
public void execute() {
    String clientName = someObject.getInformation(); //using this string while logging the metric
    logMetric(className + clientName);
    if(SomeClass.someStaticMethod(someMapObject, someOtherClassObject){
        // some code
    }

}
```

I have added only this line in my code after which that unit test case started failing with error : "Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded" error"

```
String someInformation = someObject.getInformation();
```

I got this string & added that string to a metric which we were already logging.
The line which has started throwing the error is this :

```
PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(SomeClass.class, "myStaticMethod", Map.class, SomeOtherClass.class);
```

I am scratching my head for a few days now but not able to find the root cause. I am very new to this mocking stuff. It doesn't look like I have made any change related to matcher. I am just getting a string & adding that string to a already existing metric. My small change looks completely unrelated to this but don't know why it has started failing the test case. 
Please help me finding the reason.

Answer (score 0):

These two points should solve your problem.

1. You are using a matcher (`Mockito.any()`) from Mockito while using EasyMock. Won't work
2. As soon as you use a matcher in an expectation, you need to use one for all parameters.

Your expectation should be something like this:

```
EasyMock.expect(SomeClass.someStaticMethod(EasyMock.any(Map.class), EasyMock.eq(SomeOtherClassObject))).andReturn(false);
```